# How to Create and Use Enum in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, enums

I am trying to create and use an `enum` type in Mongoose. I checked it out, but I'm not getting the proper result. I'm using `enum` in my program as follows:

My schema is:

```
var RequirementSchema = new mongooseSchema({
   status: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['NEW,'STATUS'],
        default: 'NEW'
    },
})
```

But I am little bit confused here, how can I put the value of an `enum` like in `Java NEW("new")`. How can I save an `enum` in to the database according to it's enumerable values. I am using it in express node.js.

Comment: This question has a ton of revisions fixing OP's typo and thus fixing the problem, which made the accepted answer a bit confusing. please consider the original array written was missing a "'": `enum: ['NEW, 'STATUS']`

Comment: @AlvaroCarvalho For future reference: Questions caused by typos **should be closed.**

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The enums here are basically String objects. Change the enum line to `enum: ['NEW', 'STATUS']` instead. You have a typo there with your quotation marks.

Comment: how do you link this to the user table? mine doesn't work. my user table i inserted this one role: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'roles', },

Comment: To be precise, what you're presenting here is an Array of Strings, not a "String object".

Comment: @matewka Ackchyually refers to an illustration of a neckbeard in which the word "actually" is intentionally misspelled so the reader reads it in the phlegmy cadence associated with nerd culture stereotypes.

Answer (score 135):

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Mongoose has several inbuilt validators. Strings have **enum** as one of the validators.
So enum creates a validator and checks if the value is given in an array.
E.g:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userType: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['user','admin'],
        default: 'user'
    },
})
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me to store default userType. How to change userType to amdin from js?

Comment: how do you link this to the user table? mine doesn't work. my user table i inserted this one     role: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'roles',
    },

Answer (score 49):

Let say we have a enum `Role` defined by

```
export enum Role {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
  USER = 'USER'
}
```

We can use it as type like:

```
{
    type: String,
    enum: Role,
    default: Role.USER,
}
```

Comment: Tests and validated properly on NestJs 7^

Comment: for a use of array instead use `roles: { type: [String], enum: Role, required: true, default: Role.DEFAULT }`

Answer (score 18):

If you would like to use TypeScript `enum` you can use it in interface `IUserSchema` but in Schema you have to use `array` (`Object.values(userRole)`).

```js
enum userRole {
    admin = 'admin',
    user = 'user'
}

interface IUserSchema extends Document {
    userType: userRole
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    userType: {
        type: String,
        enum: Object.values(userRole),
        default: userRole.user, 
        required: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Enums is String objects so for example : `enum :['a','b','c']` or probably like this 
`const listOfEn = ['a','b','c'];
=> enum: listOfEn`

Answer (score 6):

In a Schema design, you can easily add an enum value by using **enum** keyword like this: -

```
catagory: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['freeToPlay','earlyAccess','action','adventure','casual','indie','massivelyMultiplayer','racing','simulation','RPG','sports','statigy'],
    default: 'freeToPlay'
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).