# How to create a mongoose schema to accept only some discreet values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Lets say I have this schema.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TestSchema = new Schema({
  language: {
  required: true,
  default: 'eng',
  },
});

// Compile model from schema
const TestModel = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);
```

How can I configure this schema so that **language** field will only accept its value as `eng` or `hbrw`. If it recievs some other value it would return an error.

I know it can be done explicitly with if else but I want to know if it can be built into the schema.

Comment: you can use `enum` property, see this question [How to Create and Use Enum in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299477/how-to-create-and-use-enum-in-mongoose)

Comment: Thanks a lot it did answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how its done:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TestSchema = new Schema({
  language: {
    required: true,
    enum: ['eng', 'hbrw']
    default: 'eng',
  },
});

// Compile model from schema
const TestModel = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);
```

Enum field validates the coming data against the array of data given in `enum` field.

Thanks @turivishal for this solution